# Are the question pools for written exams publicly available?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa-knowledge-test

Can you download the question pool with answers for the FAA knowledge exams?

Comment: I believe that all of the potential test questions were published and made available.  I think this changed in 2008.

Comment: @757toga so you can download the 2008 pool?

Comment: I suppose if it was still publicly available you could.  But you'd have to do an internet search to find that out. There are several FAA Knowledge Test commercial publications that contain test questions for practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Question**: Can you download the question pool with answers for the FAA knowledge exams?

See this from [Airman Testing Questions & Answers](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/media/questions_answers.pdf) - see page 8 (FAA Airman Testing Standards Branch)

> **Does the FAA publish a list of all the knowledge test questions?**
>
> > The FAA does not release current knowledge test questions to the public. You may, however, access samples of the airman knowledge test questions [here](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_questions).